# How would I show that an open ball is a Jordan Domain?

Tags: real-analysis

We've been covering Jordan Domains in my math class, and we've had some practice showing that sets have Jordan Content $0$. However, I'm currently struggling to show that every open ball is a Jordan Domain.

If I could simply use the boxes (shifted) from a "generalized rectangle," and show that an open ball $B_\epsilon(0)$ is a Jordan Domain if

$$\prod_{i=1}^n [-\epsilon, \epsilon]$$

is a Jordan Domain, then if I know that any "generalized rectangle" is a Jordan Domain, this would work. I can visualize this in my mind, especially for two dimensions, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

On the other hand, I am not sure how to approach the problem directly. Given $\epsilon > 0$, I'd just have to show that $\{u\in\mathbb R^n : \lvert\lvert u\rvert\rvert = \epsilon\}$ has Jordan Content 0, but I'm stuck in constructing the boxes around it. I can visualize the boxes shrinking around the edge of the n-sphere, but I can't figure out how to articulate it.

How can I show that an open ball is a Jordan Domain?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon >r>0$ so $\{u\in\mathbb R^n : ||u|| = \epsilon\}\subset \{u\in\mathbb R^n :  \epsilon - r < ||u|| < \epsilon +r \}$ and that set is from size (measure) $\pi( (\epsilon +r)^2 - (\epsilon - r)^2 )=4\cdot \pi  \epsilon r $ (this is the diffrence between two balls).
This thing happens for all $r$ so the set is a Jordan set.
Q.E.D

Comment: So you are using the shell of thickness epsilon (or so) around the sphere? My book defines Jordan Content 0 with boxes (cartesian products of closed intervals $[a, b]$), so I don't know if I could do it this way

Comment: The two defines equal. You can try and allways cover whis smaller boxes. Like with rational dots whis small sizes and use the fact that your set is compact.